# Logout users with custom devise gem in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In admin section, I'm showing a list of currently logged in users. Now admin can select one or more user/users and destroy their session(logout them).Please help me ,i stuck here last 2 week. i also tried this approach

```
 def sign_out_user
      @selected_user = params[:user_ids]
       for ur in @selected_user
      usr= User.find(ur)
      sign_out usr  
     end
    redirect_to "/users/login_history"
end
```

Comment: What happens? Are you getting an error? They're not signing out? Are you sure `params[:user_ids]` has any ids in it?

Comment: No actually what happening after use this code ,admin itself logged out only. but when going to abort and checking user_id that id is different.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the session is stored in the cookie on the client. Therefore you cannot "log out" user without adding some sort of generational session keys, etc. etc.
The easiest way to accomplish the "log out" behavior, is to move the session to database.
For example: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SessionStore.html
Then you can destroy those objects, and the user will be effectively logged out.

Comment: Will you elaborate please how to implement or resolve this problem.

Comment: Use one of the thousands of tutorials that explain how to do that. For example: http://problemateek.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/using-activerecord-session-store-in.html